# change class in javascript by d3 select and filter

Tags: javascript, if-statement, d3.js, filter, bootstrap-4

I have a function like below.

First, I change all class to "badge badge-secondary".
Then, check text in span. If it is "right" and clicked, then change to "badge badge-primary".
Else, it is "wrong" and clicked, changing to "class", "badge badge-danger".

Can I make my code more concise and righter?

```
function updateOrderType(ansType) {
    lastAnsType = ansType;
    var ansBadge = d3.select("#anstype").selectAll("span.badge");
    ansBadge.attr("class", "badge badge-secondary");
    ansBadge.filter(function() {
        if (d3.select(this).text() == ansType) {
            return d3.select(this).text() == "right";
        }
    }).attr("class", "badge badge-primary");
    ansBadge.filter(function() { 
        if (d3.select(this).text() == ansType) {
            return d3.select(this).text() == "wrong";
        }
    }).attr("class", "badge badge-danger");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code was a bit difficult to understand but according to the logic you wrote in the intro, I suggest using the following:

```
function updateOrderType(ansType) {
    var ansBadge = d3.select("#anstype").selectAll("span.badge");

    ansBadge.forEach(function() {
        var oElement = d3.select(this);

        if (/**CLICKED**/) {
            var sText = oElement.text();

            if(sText === "right") {
                oElement.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-primary");
            } else if(sText === "wrong") {
                oElement.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-danger");
            } else {
                oElement.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-secondary");
            }

        } else {
            oElement.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-secondary");
        }
    }
}
```

Your code iterated through the *ansBadge* array almost 5 times, evaluating 1 *if* statement in each round. My suggestion above iterates 1 time and has 3 *if*s at tops. You can even improve this if you check if the element is **not** clicked (in the outer *if*), since it is more likely to be the case.

In this code four types of elements are handled:

- clicked & "right" > **primary**
- clicked & "wrong" > **danger**
- clicked with any text > **secondary**
- not clicked with any text > **secondary**

Answer (score 0):

A simplification of georgina95 answer

```
function updateOrderType(ansType) {
    var ansBadge = d3.select("#anstype").selectAll("span.badge");

    ansBadge.forEach(function() {
        var oElement = d3.select(this);
        var newClass = "badge badge-secondary";

        if (/**CLICKED**/) {
            var sText = oElement.text();

            if(sText === "right") {
                newClass = "badge badge-primary";
            } else if(sText === "wrong") {
                newClass = "badge badge-danger";
            }
        }
        oElement.setAttribute("class", newClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Further simplification with just one line within the `forEach` would be: `d3.select(this).setAttribute("class", "badge badge-"+(/**CLICKED**/ ? d3.select(this).text() === 'right' ? "primary" : "danger" : "secondary"))`. I'm a fan of ternary operators and so posted this. :)

Comment: @Shashank: using multiple `?` really needs `()` to add readability and prevent nasty bugs because it is right-associative.

Comment: Yes @riov8. Agreed. I do use that a lot and yes I do make sure I use `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all your helping.
first, I can't use `forEach` with d3.select (v4). It's a object which doesn't use `attr` but `setAttribute`. So I has to change my code:

```
function updateOrderType(ansType) {
    d3.select("#ordertype").selectAll("span").each(function() {
        var badgeText = this.textContent;
        if(ansType === badgeText) {
                if(ansType === "right") {
                    this.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-primary");
                } else if (ansType === "wrong") {
                    this.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-danger");
                } else {
                    this.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-secondary");
                }
        } else {
                this.setAttribute("class", "badge badge-secondary");
        } 
    });
}
```